# PyAudio OSError: [Errno -9986] Internal PortAudio error

Tags: python, pyaudio, portaudio

I'm trying to run PyAudio on OSX on a MacBook Air but I keep getting the error:

```
||PaMacCore (AUHAL)|| Error on line 1316: err='-66748', msg=Unknown Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 15, in <module>
    stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
  File "/Users/carlbengtsson/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/stickerapp-ml/sound-detection/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 750, in open
    stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/carlbengtsson/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/sound-detection/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 441, in __init__
    self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
OSError: [Errno -9986] Internal PortAudio error
```

I'm running Python 3.8.2 and have installed PortAudio using brew. Anyone having had this issue before, having any ideas on where to even start debugging this or alternatives for sound recognition? Thanks

Comment: I'm not really sure exactly what's wrong. But i assumed you installed it using `pip install pyaudio`? You could try to uninstall and install it again using `pipwin`. `pip install pipwin` then `py -m pipwin install pyaudio` or `pip install pyaudio`

Comment: Another problem could also be because of the version of Python. Perhaps try Python 3.7?

Comment: Thanks for your reply but pipwin gives me error when running, `ERROR: PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`which I'm thinking is because I'm on a Mac and OS X? Also Python 3.7 gave the exact same error. Any other ideas are very welcome!

Comment: You could try to run it in a virtual env. Either using python by running `python -m venv .` and `Scripts\activate` to activate it. Or you could use anaconda if u have it installed by running `conda create -n <venv name> python=3.6` and `conda activate <venv name>` then try to uninstall and use the same way to install in the venv before running the python file from the venv.

Comment: But there are other alternatives to PyAudio. https://realpython.com/playing-and-recording-sound-python/

Comment: Thank you for your help! Tried running different Python versions in vent and also testing sound device but with the same PortAudio error `||PaMacCore (AUHAL)|| Error on line 1277: err='-66748', msg=Unknown Error
PortAudioError: Error opening InputStream: Internal PortAudio error [PaErrorCode -9986]` Seems as if both libraries depend on PortAudio and the error is within PortAudio it self. Not sure on how to debug that thought.

Comment: this solution no longer works in MacOS Monterey

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I started getting this error as well after upgrading to Big Sur.

There seems to be an issue with compiling portaudio against macOS SDK 11. Downgrading XCode to 12.1 (which uses macOS SDK 10.5) on Big Sur has reportedly fixed the issue which is currently being tracked here: https://github.com/PortAudio/portaudio/issues/218#issuecomment-731310548.

Alternatively, now reinstalling from `--HEAD` seems to work for me.

```
brew uninstall portaudio
brew install portaudio --HEAD
```

Comment: This solved the problem for me, huge thanks!

Comment: Been looking for this for hours! This works! :D Thanks

Comment:    Big (Sur) Thank You!

Comment: Life saver! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you recently updated to BigSur? I have seen this with another program after the update.

Comment: Yes! I quite recently upgraded to BigSur but didn't run PortAudio before that so can't tell if that caused the problem or not. Did you see any solutions to make it run on BigSur? Thanks