# Python - install pyaudio on Mac

Tags: python, macos, pyaudio, apple-m1, portaudio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7i9Y.jpg)

I tried to install pyaudio with 'pip3 install pyaudio' on MacOS M1, before installed brew portaudio but it doesn't install. Error on screen.

Solution:
First I use this command 'sudo find / -name "portaudio.h"' and this show my path to portaudio, copied last path to option and paste this command:
'pip install --global-option='build_ext' --global-option='-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/HEAD-a4aacd1/include/' --global-option='-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/HEAD-a4aacd1/lib' pyaudio'

Comment: Looks like pip is trying to build [x86_64 (Intel/AMD/etc. architecture)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64), which is different from the instruction set used by your [M1 chip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M1) - that's the issue, though knowing that probably won't help you get this working, unfortunately 

Comment: there is nothing you can do(without having to do some complicated changes), because M1 and x86_64 are not the same

Answer (score 0):

First try to install portaudio with "--HEAD" parameter:

```
brew install portaudio --HEAD
```

Comment: [other same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65432130/pyaudio-oserror-errno-9986-internal-portaudio-error)

Comment: still this same error